# How to Get the Dll path from the hard Disk?

Tags: c++

I have created a subkey under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE using RegCreateKeyEx where in i m saving the NAME,TYPE DATA(Path of the dll on hardd disk).
1.I have set value as the name of the Dll i m registering using Regsvr32.
2. I have set the  type to REG_SZ using RegSetValueEx.
Now,i need to set the Data as the path of the Dll(Hard disk path).
Can anyone help me out?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you executing code *in* the DLL when you want to do this? Assuming that is the case, DllMain is passed a module handle when your DLL is first loaded. Pass this module handle to [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the full path to your DLL.

Comment: GetModuleFileName gives me the path of regsvr.exe but not the path of the Dll i m executing the code in ..can u say me where i m getting worng?     GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, _MAX_PATH) and now i want to set the data (as the path of Dll i m executing the code in) stored in buffer

Comment: I needed to get handle for GetModuleHandle. And that worked.Thanks alot

Comment: You could use the HMODULE passed to DllMain in your library. That was the intent. Anyway, glad it worked for you. I respectfully ask you mark  this (and any other answers you find on StackOverflow) as the answer to your question by hitting the green checkbox next to the answer. Thank you.